# OnItemClickListener doesn't work with LocationManager

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm trying to send co-ordinates to MapsActivity, and I wanted to test the code with toasts, but it doesn't create any toast. Anything else works well...

My original code had intents and I saw that they are not working, to check, I added toasts and I saw that still not working.

Rows include only two TextViews. Nothing else.

Also I tried to send data with buttons, and buttons were not working too...

I'm sorry, I probably have bad English so I wish I explained my problem well.

Following codes are short version of my MainActivity.java.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {
    private TextView latituteField;

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> studentList;
    private TextView longitudeField;
    private ListView lsv;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private String provider;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lsv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
         ...
    }
    ...
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
// I'm refreshing the page if location changed, so the reason of running this code is this.
        lsv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"A",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }
        });
    }
    ...
//Here comes the AsyncTask,
    class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        // Hashmap for ListView
        String viewcor;
        private RequestTask(String coord) {
            this.viewcor= coord;
        }
        ...
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            //TextView AsA = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            ListView ssss = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
            //AsA.setText(s+"");
            final ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    MainActivity.this, studentList,
                    R.layout.lust, new String[]{"id","mesafe"}, new int[]{R.id.name, R.id.mesafe});
            ssss.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
```

Comment: Don't use Toast for logging. Use android.util.Log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `.show()` to `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"A",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);`

like this: `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"A",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`